# OnClick type image

Tags: javascript, imagem, input, onclick

Estou com dificuldade de fazer um evento `onclick` funcionar. Queria trocar uma imagem de um input tipo image.
Fiz um teste com um simples alert e também não foi chamado a função. 
Aqui está parte do meu código.

---

```
<div class="bg-secund">
  <input type="image" src="img\0.gif" id="1" onclick="click()" />
</div>

<script>
function click() {
  document.getElementById("1").src = "img/0.gif ";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Para além do que o João disse repara que neste momento a tua função muda a imagem para a mesma imagem. Muda o nome da imagem que queres ter...

Answer (score 1):

Já existe uma função com nome `click()` no javascript, na hora que ele cria o handle do atributo `onclick`. Tente mudando o nome da função:

```
<div class="bg-secund">
    <input type="image" src="img\0.gif" id="1" onclick="func()">
</div>
<script>
    function func()
    {
        document.getElementById("1").src = "img/0.gif";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlw pelas dicas João e Sergio.. conseguir da um jeito.. segue parte da minha solução no momento.
fiz um joguinho da memoria com imagens.. vários desses inputs que troca as imagens de acordo com um vetor de imagens que é preenchido aleatoriamente a cada inicio de partida.

function trocar(i) {
    var numi, comp1, comp2;

```
if(numi == 0)
    comp1 = i;
if(numi == 1)
    comp2 = i

numi = numi + 1;

var x = imgAleatoria[i];
document.getElementById(i).src = x;

if(numi == 2){
compare(comp1, comp2);
numi = comp1 = comp2 = 0;
}
```

}